# Why is my WPF Events Tab gone?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I cannot see it any more in Visual Studio 2010. How can I do to get it back?

I have no addins as I just installed VS Studio.

Nevertheless this occurs on an existing solution with many projects inside. When I create a new WPF project from scratch the tab reappears.

Comment: Tell us what you've already tried.  Have you restarted VS and/or your machine?  Have you run repair on the VS installation?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like a piece of UI is missing from your Visual Studio display.  Try the following to get it to show back up in it's original location

- Tools -> Import / Export Settings
- Select "Reset all settings" and hit Next
- Save your current settings if you desire and hit Next
- Pick the profile of your choice and hit "Finish"

Answer (score 1):

Possible ways to fix:

1. Try remove all add-ins and
   extensions.
2. Tools -> Import And Export Setting
   -> Reset all settings
3. Repair Visual Studio installation.

It's not possible to give exact solution with such description of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your **User Options file** is broken.

To fix it, do the following:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Go to the folder in which your .sln file reside
3. **Delete the User Options file**
4. Open the solution again
5. The Events tab is back!

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the Properties Window? If the Properties Window is displayed, click on the yellow lightning bolt button towards the top. That will show you the events for the currently selected WPF element. If the Properties Window isn't open, press F4.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, but rather where the focus is set in your visual studio instance design view.  From the design view click the window and then do properties (F4).  This will enable the events to show and be set from the properties tag. Just make sure the focus is set on the proper item from which you want to set the events (dropdownlist, window, ect.).  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I clicked on the "Design" tab in the bottom and the "Lightning bolt" (Event tabs) reappeared, then it was still available after going into "Source" view mode.

Hope this helps someone.